# How to find the equivalence classes of a formal language complement?

Tags: equivalence-relations, formal-languages, regular-expressions

> Let $L=\{\sum^*-(\{\epsilon, a,b\}\cup \{bba^i|i\ge 0\})\}$ be a language over $\sum=\{a,b,c\}$. Find the equivalence classes of relation $R_L$ which is defined as follows: $xR_Ly \iff \forall z\in \sum^*:xz\in L \iff yz \in L$.

We learned a theorem that $R_L=R_{L'}$ where $L'$ is the complement of $L$. So to find $R_L$ of $\{\sum^*-(\{\epsilon, a,b\}\cup \{bba^i|i\ge 0\})\}$ is equivalent to find $\{\epsilon, a,b\}\cup \{bba^i|i\ge 0\}$.

$\{\epsilon, a,b\}\cup \{bba^i|i\ge 0\}=\{\epsilon, a,b,bba^*\}$. So there're $4$ equivalence classes:
$$
S_1=\epsilon\\
S_2=a\\S_2=b\\S=bba^*
$$.

However the solution to this problem mentions the fifth class: 
$$
c\Sigma^*+a\Sigma^++b(a+c)\Sigma^*+bb\Sigma^*(b+c)\Sigma^*
$$
I don't understand what this class represents. It seems that it actually represents the words in $L'$. But if so why are we adding it as these words are not in $L$?

Comment: I think we should interpret $R_L = R_{L'}$ as "there is a bijection (possibly even an isomorphism, I don't know the theorem you're referring to) between $R_L$ and $R_{L'}$" rather than a literal equality, because say let $L = \{\varepsilon\}$, then $R_L = \{\{\varepsilon\}\}$ but $R_{L'} = \{\Sigma \Sigma^*\}$, right?

Comment: $R_L=R_L'$ means that $R_L$ and $R_L'$ have the same the equivalence classes.

Comment: actually now it makes sense to me why the fifth eq. class is in $R_L$ because we need a class for all the words that are not in $L$ so for any $z\in\sum^*: xz\notin L\iff xy\notin L$, so $xR_Ly$

Comment: Yes, I think so too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to show that the Nerode equivalence classes are the same for a language $L$ and its complement $L'$. $$
xR_Ly \iff \left(\forall z\in \sum^*:xz\in L \iff yz \in L\right) \\
xR_{L'}y \iff \left(\forall z\in \sum^*:xz\in L' \iff yz \in L'\right)
$$
Since the strings in $L'$ are exactly the strings not in $L$, then $$
xz\in L \iff xz\not\in L' \\
\left(xz\in L \iff yz \in L\right) \iff \left(xz\not\in L' \iff yz \not\in L'\right) \iff \left(xz\in L' \iff yz \in L'\right)
$$
Therfore,
$$
\left(\forall z\in \sum^*:xz\in L \iff yz \in L\right) \iff \left(\forall z\in \sum^*:xz\in L' \iff yz \in L'\right) \\
xR_Ly \iff xR_{L'}y 
$$

---

You seem to have forgotten the equivalences classes that contains all strings that are not accepted. However, I would strongly caution you not to try to find the equivalence classes the way that you have.

One reasons is, there may be multiple equivalence classes of strings that are not accepted (for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2995862/507748)). These will not always be obvious and you may not be able to guess them from the definition.

Another reason is, the accepting equivalence classes that you read off may not be separate equivalence classes. For instance, what if we changed your language just a bit: the language generated by $\{\epsilon,a,b,bba^*,aba^*\}$. You might similarly claim that the accepting equivalence classes are $$
S_1=\{\epsilon\} \\
S_2=\{a\} \\
S_3=\{b\} \\
S_4=\{bba^*\} \\
S_5=\{aba^*\} \\
$$
However, this is not true. The strings $a$ and $b$ must be in the same equivalence class, since they cannot be seperated by any $z\in\Sigma^*$.

For these reasons, I would **highly** recommend that you find the minimal DFA for a language to find the equivalence classes. Your way happened to work (although you missed the last equivalence class), but for many other languages it will give you a very wrong answer.

Comment: Indeed why couldn't we have written the last class: $c\Sigma^*+a\Sigma^++b(a+c)\Sigma^*+bb\Sigma^*(b+c)\Sigma^*$ as $4$ separate equivalence classes?

Comment: @Yos Because the relation specifies that two elements are in the same equivalence class **if and only if** for all $z\in \Sigma^*$ either $xz$ and $yz$ are both accepted or both rejected. Consider the strings $c$ and $a$. Can you find a $z$ such that $cz$ is accepted but $az$ is not or vice versa? If you cannot, then they must be in the same equivalence class.

Comment: so if the eq. class had $c\Sigma^*+a\Sigma^*$ we could've split the class into two right? because $c\epsilon\notin L$ but $a\epsilon\in L$

Comment: Whoops, used a bad example, misread the expression. Instead consider the strings $ca$ and $ac$.

Comment: @Yos To be clear, we can never split an equivalence class. The equivalence classes are exactly determined by the language. Two different sets of equivalence classes are not possible.

Comment: Thanks for including a proof! Indeed it is easy to show (rewrite in a way which is easier for myself): $$\begin{align} x \sim_L y &\iff (\forall z \in \Sigma^* \ xz \in L \iff yz \in L) \\ &\iff (\forall z \in \Sigma^* \ xz \notin L \iff yz \notin L) \\ &\iff (\forall z \in \Sigma^* \ xz \in L' \iff yz \in L') \\ &\iff x \sim_{L'} y \end{align}$$