# finding equivalence classes of $R_L$ in automata(Nerode)

Tags: computer-science, equivalence-relations, automata

i am having trouble understanding this concept. would really appreciate your corrections so i could learn and improve.

1)$L=\left\{w\:\in \Sigma^* |\:w\:begins\:and\:ends\:with\:aa\right\}$

2)$L=\Sigma^* \:-\:\left(\left\{\epsilon ,\:a\:,b\right\}\:\cup \left\{bba^i|\:i\:\ge 0\right\}\right)$

(both are over $\Sigma = {a,b,c}$, but different problems

i don't understand this, but i'll try anyway:

1)equivalence classes:

$S_1 = (b+c)\Sigma ^*$

$S_2 = \epsilon$

$S_3 = aa + aa\Sigma^*aa$ (i think there's a mistake here)

$S_4 = aa \Sigma^*(b+c)$

2)i really don't know, but i'll try anyway:

$S_1 = \epsilon$

$S_2 = a$

$S_3 = b$

$S_4 = bba*$

(i don't know how to do $S_5$, would really appreciate your help with it).

tried to do my best, even though i know i've had errors and mistakes there. please show me the right way so i could learn what i've done wrong.

thank you very much.

side question if possible: how can i find the words that separate between the equivalence classes? thank you very much for your help

Comment: Ad your side question: If you know the appropriate constructions, the easiest method is, by far, constructing a DFA (or NFA) for $L$ and then minimizing its set of states. Each state of the resulting DFA then corresponds to an equivalence class, and pointing out a representative amounts to simply finding a word in the DFA which brings it to that state. See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995862/dfa-minimization-finding-all-nerode-equivalence-classes).

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. after i will obtain the equivalence classes i'll try to find the separating words. thank you again for your link